# Remove Timestamp from an artifact name while keeping the Build number

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory

I am using `Maven artifactory build` to store war files on the artifactory.

```
       def server = Artifactory.newServer url: 'ARTIFACTORY_URL', username: 'USERNAME', password: 'PASSWORD'
       def rtMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild()
       rtMaven.deployer server: server, releaseRepo: 'libs-release-local', snapshotRepo: 'libs-snapshot-local'
       rtMaven.tool = 'MAVEN_JENKINS_TOOL'
       rtMaven.opts = '-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/PATH_OF_TRUSTSTORE'
       def buildInfo = rtMaven.run pom: 'pom.xml', goals: 'clean install -DskipTests -Dv=${BUILD_NUMBER} '
       server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo
```

The artifactory is storing the war files with a `timestamp` and `build number` appended to the file name.

I am using `unique` version in `Maven Snapshot Version Behavior` under `ARTIFACTORY_URL/admin/repository/local/libs-snapshot-local`. I tried `non-unique` version but that removes timestamp as well as build number from the artifact name.

I want the artifact to have build number, which should be in sync with `Jenkins build number`, and no timestamp to be included in the artifact name.

I also tried by changing version to `1.0-SNAPSHOT-$(v)` and using command `-Dv={BUILD_NUMBER}` in the script while having `Maven Snapshot Version Behavior` as `Deployer`.